# why showing Warning : com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks while generate signed apk in android

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

android studio run generate signed apk showing this error..

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks: can't find referenced class com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.Tweaks$TweakType
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

Build.gradle

i'm modify it minifyennabled:false change to minifyennabled:true this error accrued

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question. when minifyEnabled is false is it still happening?

Comment: question changed please check